# Compile error end of statement with " "

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors

I want the following to be displayed in a cell but I get a compile error end of statement. and/or only WA displayed not "WA" in the cell. What should I add to this code?

```
ActiveCell = "=IF(Rater!D6 = "WA",'Unity Country rate'!F55,VLOOKUP(Rater!E12,'Country rate'!A18:B205,2,FALSE))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(Rater!D6=""WA"",'Unity Country rate'!F55,VLOOKUP(Rater!E12,'Country rate'!A18:B205,2,FALSE))"
```

You need double quotes within the larger quotes.

---

To explain that better, think of linking strings together:

```
x = "cat"
y = " and "
z = "dog"
cell(1,1).value = x & y & z 'cat and dog
```

Filling in the variables:

```
cell(1,1).value = "cat" & " and " & "dog"
```

Looks funny, but you are adding items, so need that & sign and the actual written sections are within quotations.  If you have internal quotations within the string, and they need to be displayed, you will need to essentially close and re-open the string so those additional quotations are captured:

```
cell(1,1).value = "cat and dog"
cell(1,1).value = "cat ""and"" dog" 'will add quotations within, such that cat "and" dog
```